# Ubuntu 17.04 keyboard suddenly stopped working

Tags: keyboard, 17.10, wayland

After an upgrade to 17.10 internal keyboard and touchpad suddenly stopped working. 
This problem occurs even during startup, so I can't even boot from USB. 
This problem probably occured after I created a new user account, but I deleted it in the meantime and no change. After the installation, everything worked still well. 
However, I can use external USB mouse.
Can someone please help me? I'm completely lost.

```
sudo lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 5986:0673 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 062a:0000 Creative Labs Optical mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05dc:a81d Lexar Media, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

robin@robin:~$ sudo dmesg
[    0.073073] PCI: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-3f] at [mem 0xe0000000-0xe3ffffff] (base 0xe0000000)
[    0.073073] PCI: MMCONFIG at [mem 0xe0000000-0xe3ffffff] reserved in E820
[    0.073073] PCI: Using configuration type 1 for base access
[    0.076289] HugeTLB registered 2.00 MiB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
[    0.076289] ACPI: Added _OSI(Module Device)
[    0.076289] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Device)
[    0.076289] ACPI: Added _OSI(3.0 _SCP Extensions)
[    0.076289] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Aggregator Device)
[    0.083277] ACPI Error: No handler for Region [ECF2] (ffff8fb8bf148a68) [EmbeddedControl] (20170531/evregion-166)
[    0.083289] ACPI Error: Region EmbeddedControl (ID=3) has no handler (20170531/exfldio-299)
[    0.083297] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.EC0._REG, AE_NOT_EXIST (20170531/psparse-550)
[    0.085651] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.085663] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF8FB8BE5B9800 000634 (v01 PmRef  Cpu0Ist  00003000 INTL 20120711)
[    0.086039] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.086049] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF8FB8BE61AC00 0003A5 (v01 PmRef  Cpu0Cst  00003001 INTL 20120711)
[    0.086773] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.086783] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF8FB8BE61F200 00015F (v01 PmRef  ApIst    00003000 INTL 20120711)
[    0.087110] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.087119] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF8FB8BE634D80 00008D (v01 PmRef  ApCst    00003000 INTL 20120711)
[    0.088100] ACPI: EC: EC started
[    0.088102] ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
[    0.308133] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.EC0_: Used as first EC
[    0.308137] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.EC0_: GPE=0x16, EC_CMD/EC_SC=0x66, EC_DATA=0x62
[    0.308139] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.EC0_: Used as boot DSDT EC to handle transactions
[    0.308140] ACPI: Interpreter enabled
[    0.308179] ACPI: (supports S0 S3 S4 S5)
[    0.308182] ACPI: Using IOAPIC for interrupt routing
[    0.308237] PCI: Using host bridge windows from ACPI; if necessary, use "pci=nocrs" and report a bug
[    0.366864] ACPI: Power Resource [USBC] (on)
[    0.374234] ACPI: Power Resource [CLK0] (off)
[    0.374747] ACPI: Power Resource [CLK0] (off)
[    0.374821] ACPI: Power Resource [CLK1] (off)
[    0.381014] ACPI: Power Resource [ID3C] (on)
[    0.386582] ACPI: Power Resource [FN00] (off)
[    0.387432] ACPI: PCI Root Bridge [PCI0] (domain 0000 [bus 00-ff])
[    0.387441] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS supports [ExtendedConfig ASPM ClockPM Segments MSI]
[    0.387516] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC failed (AE_ERROR); disabling ASPM
[    0.387536] acpi PNP0A08:00: [Firmware Info]: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-3f] only partially covers this bridge
```

Or can this be a hardware problem?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

For me wifi was stopped working after couple of restarts, post 17.04 to 17.10 upgrade. I chose earlier stable version of kernel from grub, and things are running fine now. You may want to check out `dmesg` output, that's how i got the hint that something is wrong around it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't go back because this is the only kernel I installed and I can't navigate in the grub Menu, since keyboard isn't working.

Comment: what kernel version did you use instead?

Comment: I am currently using 4.10.0-37-generic and was facing problems on 4.13.0-16-generic

Comment: Did you try getting into your BIOS or UEFI boot menu? It may be a hardware problem if you can 't use your keyboard even before grub menu.

Comment: It finally was a hardware problem. I opened the device and saw the connection to the keyboard was a bit dirty and cleaned it.