# Keyboard/touchpad are not working on Ubuntu 20.04 for HP Elitebook Folio 1040

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, touchpad, hp

I have an HP EliteBook Folio 1040 which worked fine under Ubuntu 18.04. After an upgrade, the internal keyboard and touchpad stopped working:

- When I add an external keyboard / mouse, they work
- In the bios, the internal keyboard works. Hence it's not a hardware issue

How can I fix this?

### Diagnostic information

- [dmesg output](https://gist.github.com/MartinThoma/2cb41218aeec3d7c24ab633f322ea367)

### Similar questions which didn't help

- [Ubuntu 17.04 keyboard suddenly stopped working](https://askubuntu.com/q/967556/10425)
- [On-board keyboard and trackpad not working 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/1282269/10425)
   - blacklisting `intel_vbtn` had no effect

Comment: That sounds like a kernel problem. Check this out: [On-board keyboard and trackpad not working 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1282260/on-board-keyboard-and-trackpad-not-working-20-04/1282269#1282269)

Comment: @lynx blacklisting intel_vbtn had no effect